# "Unable to resolve service for type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager" - Replaced type won't work after scaffolding but ok before scaffolding

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I am trying to customize the Identity package according to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-3.0#customize-the-model).

Following the instructions, I created `ApplicationUser` by sub-classing the base `IdentityUser`. I changed the injected type to `.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>`. Things worked out fine. The only view that had to be changed was _LoginPartial because it had `@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser>`. I just had to change `IdentityUser` to `ApplicationUser`. All the other Razor pages in the Identity package worked fine.

However, when I scaffolded the Identity package, I will get the following whenever one of the overridden Identity Razor pages is accessed:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]'

I now have to change all references of `IdentityUser` in the generic types in all the *.cshtml.cs files to `ApplicationUser`.

My question is why was it working without modification before scaffolding, when I had already injected with type `ApplicationUser`?